# How to fill NaN values according to the data type in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, fillna

Greeting everyone. I have an excel file that I need to clean and fill NaN values according to column data types, like if column data type is object I need to fill "NULL" in that column and if data types is integer or float 0 needs to be filled in those columns.

So far I have tried 2 method to do the job but no luck, here is the first

```
df = pd.read_excel("myExcel_files.xlsx")
```

## using bulit method for selecting columns by data types

```
df.select_dtypes(include='int64').fillna(0, inplace=True)

df.select_dtypes(include='float64').fillna(0.0, inplace=True)

df.select_dtypes(include='object').fillna("NULL", inplace=True)
```

and the output that I get is not an error but a warning **and there is no change in data frame**

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4259: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  **kwargs
```

## as the first one was slice error so I thought doing it one column at a time, here is the code

```
df = pd.read_excel("myExcel_files.xlsx")

#get the list of all integer columns
int_cols = list(df.select_dtypes('int64').columns)

#get the list of all float columns
float_cols = list(df.select_dtypes('float64').columns)

#get the list of all object columns
object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes('object').columns)

#looping through if each column to fillna
for i in int_cols:
    df[i].fillna(0,inplace=True)

for f in float_cols:
    df[f].fillna(0,inplace=True)

for o in object_cols:
    df[o].fillna("NULL",inplace=True)
```

Both of my methods doesn't work.
Many thanks for any help or suggestions. 
Regards -[Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11515979/manish-chaudhary)

Comment: you either do: `df[i] = df[i].fillna(0)` or `df[i].fillna(0,inplace=True)`

Comment: i tried both this one df[i] = df[i].fillna(0) makes the whole column None and this one df[i].fillna(0,inplace=True) throws warning

Comment: you should give sample input data. otherwise we can't reproduce your problem. its working for me on a simple example

Comment: thanks @luigigi, it worked now, df[i] = df[i].fillna(0) doesn;t support inplace argument

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that instead of using `select_dtypes` and iterating over columns you can take the `.dtypes` of your DF and replace float64's wth 0.0 and objects with "NULL"... you don't need to worry about int64's as they generally won't have missing values to fill (unless you're using `pd.NA` or a nullable int type), so you might be able to do a single operation of:

```
df.fillna(df.dtypes.replace({'float64': 0.0, 'O': 'NULL'}), inplace=True)
```

You can also add `downcast='infer'` so that if you have what can be `int64`s in a `float64` column, you end up with `int64`s, eg given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1.0, 2, np.nan, 4],
    'b': [np.nan, 'hello', np.nan, 'blah'],
    'c': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, np.nan]
})
```

Then:

```
df.fillna(df.dtypes.replace({'float64': 0.0, 'O': 'NULL'}), downcast='infer', inplace=True)
```

Will give you (note column `a` was downcast to int but `c` remains float):

```
   a      b    c
0  1   NULL  1.1
1  2  hello  1.2
2  0   NULL  1.3
3  4   blah  0.0
```

Comment: cells ='A1:T635785'
df = pd.read_excel("Compiled_text_clean.xlsx")

Comment: And one more question if you could help-
cells ='A1:T635785'
why the solution only works with data frame made from this code
df = pd.read_excel("Compiled_text_clean.xlsx") 
and not with this code using xlwings
df = sheet.range(cells).options(pd.DataFrame, index =False).value
as I am having a huge file and xlwings runs pretty fast than pd.read_excel method

Comment: @Manish I'm not sure - I don't think I've ever used xlwings... Does it return a DF with the same `.dtypes` that `pd.read_excel` does?

Comment: Yes, the dataframe is exactly the same but when run this code on it gives me the same error of SettingWithCopyWarning

Comment: @Manish curious... don't think I can help much there as I don't have xlwings installed and probably don't have any data guaranteed to reproduce the same issue to test with...